# How to add custom email notification in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

As title mentioned, is there any possible way to add email notification just like email to customer on cancelled order.
I would like to email to notice on cancelled order due to time limit of pending payment.

Any possible way??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a custom hooked function in **`woocommerce_email_recipient_cancelled_order`** filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_cancelled_order', 'adding_customer_email_recipient_to_cancelled', 10, 2 );
function adding_customer_email_recipient_to_cancelled( $recipient, $order ){
    if( is_admin() ) return $recipient;

    $billing_email = $order->get_billing_email();
    $recipient .= ', ' . $billing_email; 
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works on WooCommerce 3.0+

Answer (score 0):

You can use action hook *woocommerce_order_status_cancelled*, this action is executed when order status is changed to cancelled.

In example:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_cancelled', function($order_id){
  //send email here
}, 10, 1);
```